# "Вот так так!"

Tags: пунктуация

Вчера читала одну книгу, и там данный возглас был написан через дефис: "Вот так-так!" Но меня терзают смутные сомнения)))
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно писать эту фразу?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Вот так так!   - это устойчивое сочетание для выражения удивления.  Дефис здесь не ставится, так это особая синтаксическая конструкция. Можно ПРЕДПОЛОЖИТЬ, что при ее образовании прослеживается определенное соответствие с выражениями вида: "на юге жара так (уж) жара", "сказал так уж сказал". По аналогии получается: вот так (так уж) так.

Дефис пишется в оценочных выражениях "так-так", "так-так-так", но они имеют другое значение и построены по принципу повтора для выражения экспрессии (сравнить: еле-еле, чуть-чуть), слитное произношение без паузы.